# Firefox ignores JavaScript override of form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, submit

I have this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-search.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="my_Init();">
<div>
<form name="id_msearchform" onsubmit="my_EventHandler_Action(); return false;">
  <input type="text" name="id_searchphrase" value="example"></input>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="id_searchsubmit" value="Search"></input>
</form>
<br><br>
<div id="id_searchresults">No search done...</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want the browser to request a new URL. That is why "onsubmit" has "return false;". This code works in Internet Explorer, but Firefox generates a new request. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

FireBug changes between not wanting to acknowledge there is Javascript reference and showing the Javascript file without any errors... I will update this when i have more to add. I will try various thingsm e.g. try upload it to the net and see if FireFox behaves differently when not running JS on local disk.

Comment: You probably have an exception.  Set Firebug to break on errors.

Comment: let's see the `my_EventHandler_Action()` function

Comment: Do you want to use pure javascript? Because you can define a submit function on jQuery that will work on any major browser.

Comment: jQuery is nogo. I need to keep overhead down for this specific pure-JS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you haven't got any errors?

I try with a simple html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-search.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="my_Init();">
<div>
<form name="id_msearchform" onsubmit="my_EventHandler_Action(); return false;">
  <input type="text" name="id_searchphrase" value="example"></input>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="id_searchsubmit" value="Search"></input>
</form>
<br><br>
<div id="id_searchresults">No search done...</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And a simple javascript called `my-search.js` in the same path of my html with the next code:

```
var my_Init = function(){
    alert('Hello Onload');
}
var my_EventHandler_Action = function(){
    alert('Hello OnSubmit');
}
```

And it works fine.

Can you show a live demo (with dropbox or something)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a submit button, try using a button and link the javascript function to that.

Comment: That might do the desired behavior, but won't find the underlying problem, since it *should* be able to do what he wants.